# Does PHP silently optimize consecutive fseek-commands into one fseek command?

Tags: php, performance, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, internal

I am running Windows 7 - 64 bit, with the latest XAMPP version that has a 32-bit PHP version.

On testing http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php#112647 
for a very big file (bigger than PHP_MAX_INT 2147483647) I'm now pretty sure, that the consecutively following fseeks are summed up before being executed on the filepointer.

I have two questions:

1. Could I break up this summing up with reasonable means (or only with the workaround mentioned in the link above)?
2. Is this aggregation happening in PHP (as I assume, though I don't know where in PHP) or in Windows 7?

> Answering myself: Trying two workarounds with multiple seeks didn't work
>   on my system. Instead they put the filepointer to different positions
>   at under PHP_MAX_INT. (32-bit PHP only can seek up to PHP_MAX_INT +
>   8192. Reading from there on is still possible, but I don't know how far.)
>
> Therefore the question is obsolete for my specific case, as
>   32-bit PHP only can seek up to PHP_MAX_INT + 8192, whatever you do. I
>   leave the question, because two people voted it up, and might be
>   interested in a general answer.

I filed a bug report here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69213
Result: With a 64-bit PHP build it might work, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Note: I didn't try SplFileObject as suggested by someone else, as I trust the php-manual that SplFileObject should just be a layer above the usual seek, etc commands. And I have already migrated to perl for this specific task. (Which even the guy on the php bug side understood.) I won't deploy a 64 bit php build as long as it isn't mainstream. And I'm not migrating entirely to perl for just reading and writing a couple of very big files. (And it's very difficult for me to see any conceptual advantage in SplFileObject. Though the maintainers are said to be"enthusiastic" about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. It actually does something *even dumber.* Here's a snippet from the PHP source code:

```
      switch(whence) {
          case SEEK_CUR:
              offset = stream->position + offset;
              whence = SEEK_SET;
              break;
      }
```

This is in the guts of the implementation for PHP's `fseek`. What's happening here is: if you tell PHP to seek from the current position, it translates that to an "equivalent" seek from the start of the file. This only works when that offset computation doesn't overflow; if it does, well, `offset` is a signed integer, so that's undefined behavior.

And, okay, this is there because PHP buffers streams internally, so they need to do *something.* But it doesn't have to be this.

You're probably best off trying to do your work in a language that actually does what you tell it to.

Comment: That shouldn't really be a problem because read and write point changes get reduced to offsets from their current positions and the disk system isn't going to perform unnecessary seeks; it's only going to seek the head to where it needs to read and write. In this sense, seeking without reading or writing is just changing signed integers.

Comment: Take off your kernel-colored glasses. These semantics mean that no PHP program can seek very much further than `ZEND_LONG_MAX` bytes into a file, even if the filesystem and operating system are capable of it. Because PHP's implementation of `SEEK_CUR` contains undefined behavior in the formal, C-standard sense. PHP will not do what the programmer told it to do in this case, and that should be *unacceptable*.

Comment: @Alex: That fits to what I found out by trying different target seek values. (See last entry in the php-bug report I linked.) So I accept this answer. With the bug (or old code) being there, it's to no effect currently to the end user if there are other optimizations or bugs at other levels, as those other levels will never get the assumed values. I assume. I'm not into this. As written, I use perl for the single big file task.:)  Maybe you could write a bug report with the code lines you found, and maybe it will be improved. :)

Comment: @Alex: Btw: 32bit php only promises to work up to the size it does work. :) I just wonder how the linked not functioning workaround posted on the php-manual webpage could get so many upvotes. Maybe it was working in former versions. Or when php is compiled with other compilers. - Anyway much too difficult. Adding on to this the problems with writing and reading UTF-filenames on windows , php lost a bit of it's appeal to me.

Comment: @Alex My answer was based on a read of the PHP source, without considerations outside of there, except that the disk system will optimize out unnecessary seeks on the disk.  ZEND_LONG_MAX is a long and on a 64-bit system will be 64-bit. Similarly, and as I pointed out in my answer, in the PHP source, zend_fseek maps to either seek or _seeki64 depending on the system. Thus, PHP should be able to seek to any position in virtual memory space, and thus to any file position to which the OS can seek.

Answer (score 0):

If aggregation were to happen it would likely have to be as an opcode optimization or would have to occur at the low level via a buffer.

I can answer at the low level. fseek() in php is implemented using php streams. It is declared in ext/standard/file.h and defined in .c. Its implementation calls php_stream_seek() which calls through to _php_stream_seek() in streams.c. The low level implementation of this is handled through the plain streams wrapper, in which case seek calls through to either zend_seek or zend_fseek, which in turn just map through to either 32 or 64-bit *seek _*seeki64 c calls.

So... if any aggregation happens, it would seem to have to be in the opcode optimizations or even further below in the OS or hardware. Hard disks implement out-of-order fetching to reduce head seek distances and filesystem buffering systems might be able to reduce seeks that have no side-effects. If you are concerned about disk read time, the first automatically handles this. If you are concerned with perhaps thrashing memory (seeking great distances unnecessarily in the buffer) you might considered another approach. See: http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs450/disksched/disksched.html for more info on how disks avoid wasting seek time.

I hope this helps.